# KeyError with dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I was attempting to get the user to enter a city and the temperature which would be saved to a dictionary. However, Python keeps telling me that I'm getting a KeyError. Why is this happening and how do i fix this? Thank you.

```
def main():
    city = {}
    keepgoing = True
    while keepgoing:    
        user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
        for valu in user.split():
            city[valu] = city[valu]+1

        if user == "stop":
            keepgoing = False
            print(city)


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the immediate issue, replace:

```
        city[valu] = city[valu]+1
```

With:

```
        city[valu] = city.get(valu, 0) + 1
```

#### Explanation

`city.get(valu)` is just like `city[valu]` except that it provides a default value of `None` if the key doesn't exist.  `city.get(valu, 0)` is similar but it sets the default value to `0`.

#### Complete Program

Guessing at what you wanted, here is a rewrite of the code:

```
def main():
    city = {}
    while True:
        user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
        if user == "stop":
            print(city)
            break
        name, temperature = user.split()
        city[name] = temperature

main()
```

In operation:

```
Enter city followed by temperature: NYC 101
Enter city followed by temperature: HK 115
Enter city followed by temperature: stop
{'NYC': '101', 'HK': '115'}
```

Comment: Alright. That fixed the error but I'm coming up with another problem. That being that the program will assign everything to a key so, for example, if someone enters "Denver -6" the program will put {Denver:1, -6:1} into the dictionary. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @user3495234 I added a a more complete code rewrite to the end of the answer.  Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Right. That's it. Sorry for being ambiguous. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change your for-loop to look like this:

```
city = {}
while keepgoing:
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
    for valu in user.split():
        if valu not in city:
            city[value] = 0
        city[value] = city[value]+1
```

You get an error because the first time around, `valu` is not a key in `city`. As a result, `city[valu]` fails. Setting it to `0` (or some other default value) when the key doesn't exist will fix your problem

Comment: Alright. That fixed the error but I'm coming up with another problem. That being that the program will assign everything to a key so, for example, if someone enters "Denver -6" the program will put {Denver:1, -6:1} into the dictionary. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @user3495234: that's up to you to decide. You have to figure out what you want to do with `'Denver'` and `-6`. Based on the text in your question, I think you want to use one as the key and the other as the value; but your code does not reflect that.